Derivation of a homotopy between two loops on the unit circle $S^1$
In example 3 on page 89 of Basic Topology by Armstrong, we're given two loops $\alpha, \beta: [0,1] \to S^1$ based at the point 1 of $S^1$ (considered as a subset of the complex plane), given by
$$
\alpha(s)=
\begin{cases}
\exp 4\pi is & 0\leq s \leq \frac{1}{2} \\
\exp 4\pi i(2s-1) & \frac{1}{2}\leq s \leq \frac{3}{4} \\
\exp 8\pi i(1-s) & \frac{3}{4}\leq s \leq 1 \\
\end{cases}
$$
and
$$
\beta(s)=
\begin{cases}
\exp 2\pi i s & 0 \leq s \leq 1.
\end{cases}
$$
The homotopy $F$ from $\alpha$ to $\beta$ relative to $\{0,1\}$ is given by
$$
F(s,t)=
\begin{cases}
\exp \frac{4\pi is}{t+1} & 0\leq s \leq \frac{t+1}{2} \\
\exp 4\pi i(2s-1-t) & \frac{t+1}{2}\leq s \leq \frac{t+3}{4} \\
\exp 8\pi i(1-s) & \frac{t+3}{4}\leq s \leq 1. \\
\end{cases}
$$
The fact that $F(s,t)$ is continuous is evident. Furthermore,
$$
F(s,0)=
\begin{cases}
\exp 4\pi is & 0\leq s \leq \frac{1}{2} \\
\exp 4\pi i(2s-1) & \frac{1}{2}\leq s \leq \frac{3}{4} \\
\exp 8\pi i(1-s) & \frac{3}{4}\leq s \leq 1. \\
\end{cases}=\alpha(s)
$$ and
$$
F(s,1)=
\begin{cases}
\exp 2\pi is & 0\leq s \leq 1 \\
\exp 4\pi i(2s-2) & 1\leq s \leq 1 \\
\exp 8\pi i(1-s) & 1\leq s \leq 1. \\
\end{cases}=\beta(s)
$$
since the components agree at $s=1$.
How does one derive this homotopy though? I'm aware of the linear/straight-line homotopy construction for paths on a convex set, however it looks like this is constructed in a different manner. (See the image below for clarification.)


You might want to think about how to construct a homotopy between the path $$\gamma(s) = \begin{cases} \exp 4 \pi i s & 0 \leq s \leq \frac{1}{2} \ \exp 4 \pi i (1 - s) & \frac{1}{2} \leq s \leq 1 \end{cases}$$ and the constant path at 1; the given homotopy $F$ can then be constructed from this (well, if you come up with the "canonical" construction at least :) by "fiddling around until everything matches up." It's a bit like lego, in a sense.

It might also be helpful to allow yourself to replace $[0, 1]$ with another interval, say $[0, 3]$; then $\alpha$ simply has the form $$\alpha(s) = \begin{cases} \exp 2\pi i s & 0 \leq s \leq 1 \ \exp 2 \pi i s & 1 \leq s \leq 2 \ \exp 2 \pi i (1 - s) & 2 \leq s \leq 3\end{cases}$$ With this and my previous comment, find a homotopy between $\alpha$ and $$\gamma(s) = \begin{cases} \exp 2 \pi i s & 0 \leq s \leq 1 \ 1 & 1 \leq s \leq 2 \end{cases}$$ then to $\delta(s) = \exp 2 \pi i \frac{s}{3}$, and then think about how to assemble these pieces to get $F$.

You derive it by recognising linear homotopies are the simplest thing and having some experience with, say, how we prove the fundamental group is a group

@BenSteffan A homotopy between $\gamma$ and the constant path $c_1$ can be given by $H_1(s,t)=\begin{cases}\exp 4\pi i st & 0 \leq t \leq \frac{1}{2} \ \exp -4\pi (1-s)t & \frac{1}{2} \leq t \leq 1 \end{cases}$.
Essentially, for $t \in [0,1]$, we only travel a fraction $t$ of the way around the unit circle via the $\gamma$ path before going back to the starting point. For example, for $t=1/2$, we travel counterclockwise from $1$ to $-1$ and then retrace our path.

@BenSteffan For your second comment, we can construct a homotopy from $\alpha$ to $\gamma$ by constructing the obvious one from the first function of $\alpha$ to the first function of $\gamma$. And then we've already shown that we can construct a homotopy from the second and third functions of $\alpha$ to the constant path/function $1=c_1$. Since the composition of homotopic maps are homotopic, this then gives us a homotopy $H_2(s,t)$ from $\alpha$ to $\gamma$. We can then compose this with $\delta$, scaling as needed, to get our homotopy $F$.
Am I understanding the approach correctly?

@isometry Yes, exactly. Basically it's how FShrike says: If you know all of these "basic" homotopies, you can craft a complex homotopy out of them essentially just by concatenation. To get to something like Armstrong's homotopy you could write down the formula for the concatenation and then try to "optimize" a bit, by, say, trying to do interval reparametrization at the same time as actually homotoping the relevant path segments to a constant path.

Perhaps the point should also be that understanding Armstrong's homotopy in detail: For the most part any path homotopy between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ will do, so if you understand all these steps by themselves and how to concatenate them you should be perfectly well off. There's rarely any need to make the homotopy particularly elegant, or in fact to know a concrete description of the homotopy at all.

This is too long for a comment so I'm writing it here. Instead of directly constructing a homotopy between $\alpha$ and $\beta$, we can construct intermediate ones and then compose them. We first define $\alpha', \gamma, \gamma'$ by
$$
\alpha'(s)=\begin{cases}
\exp 2\pi is & 0 \leq s \leq 1 \\
\exp 2\pi is & 1 \leq s \leq 2 \\
\exp 2\pi i(1-s) & 2 \leq s \leq 3 \\ 
\end{cases}
$$
$$
\gamma(s)=\begin{cases}
\exp 2\pi is & 0 \leq s \leq 1 \\
1 & 1 \leq s \leq 2\end{cases}
$$
$$
\gamma'(s)=\begin{cases}
\exp \pi is & 0 \leq s \leq 2 \\
1 & 2 \leq s \leq 2
\end{cases}
$$
where $\alpha'$ is a re-parameterized version of $\alpha$ and $\gamma'$ is a re-parameterized version of $\gamma$.
Then, we have the following homotopies $$F_1(s,t): \alpha' \to \gamma\\ F_2(s,t): \gamma \to \gamma'\\ F_3(s,t): \gamma' \to \beta.$$
$$
F_1(s,t)=\begin{cases}
\exp 2\pi is & 0 \leq s \leq 1-t \\
\exp 2\pi is & 1-t \leq s \leq 2-t \\
\exp 2\pi i(1-s)(1-t) & 2-t \leq s \leq 3-t
\end{cases}
$$
$$
F_2(s,t)=\begin{cases}
\exp \frac{2\pi is}{t+1} & 0 \leq s \leq t+1 \\
1 & t+1 \leq s \leq 2
\end{cases}
$$
$$F_3(s,t)=\begin{cases}
\exp (t+1)\pi is & 0 \leq s \leq 2-t.
\end{cases}$$
Thus, the main difficulty is coming up with a homotopy $F_0(s,t): \alpha \to \alpha'$. Doing some linear interpolation for the intervals and also solving systems of linear equations, I was able to find
$$F_0(s,t)=\begin{cases}
\exp \frac{4\pi is}{t+1} & 0 \leq s \leq \frac{t+1}{2} \\
\exp[2\pi is(4-3t)+4\pi i(t-1)] & \frac{t+1}{2} \leq s \leq \frac{5t+3}{4} \\
\exp[(8\pi i - 6\pi it)(1-s)] & \frac{5t+3}{4} \leq s \leq 2t+1 \\
\end{cases}.
$$
We then have a homotopy $F: \alpha \to \beta$ given by
$F=F_3\circ F_2\circ F_1\circ F_0$. This is different and more complicated than the one given in Armstrong's example but it works.
